# How to make a new object in an array

Tags: reactjs

I have an autocomplete and when the user clicks on it it adds the value to the end of the label and value key.

I have an array object like this:

I want to transform my array object like this:

```
{label: "8", value: "8"}
{label: "10", value: "10"}
{label: "9", value: "9"}
```

I have tried transforming it like so:

```
  const edit = scheduleFieldData['project'].split(/,(?=")/).map(x => ({label: x, value: x}))
```

But instead I get this:

```
    [
       {"label":",8,10,9","value":",8,10,9"}
    ]
```

Any JS Gurus know how to do this? Much help is appreciated!

the value of scheduleFieldData['project'] returns a string :

,8,9

Comment: Can you clarify please, I don't understand what you have as an entry and what you need as output

Comment: I have an autocomplete and when the user clicks on it it adds the value to the end of the label and value key, if that helps!

Comment: Can you just display the entry you have please

Comment: I would also like to see the value of `scheduleFieldData['project']`

Comment: @stackblunter we can't help you without all the informations

Comment: @JulianKleine just updated for you guys

Comment: @HichamELBSI just updated for you

Comment: Okay, so just split by "," not with the regex, the positive lookahead for a `"` is not what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split by "," and filter for undefined or null values. You can even add a sort.

```js
const test = ',8,10,9';

const edit = test.split(",").filter(x => x).sort((a,b) => a - b).map(x => ({
  label: x,
  value: x
}));

console.log(edit)
```

Comment: amazing, thaank you!!